# how to count unique strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've a list comprising of numbers and names.

```
lst = ['new car', '232', 'famous bike','232', 'new car', '232plane', 'new car', 'plane232']
```

I want to count only the words like `new car, famous bike` and not numeric or alphanumeric.

Output will be 2 because there are two unique words: car, bike.

I know there's a simple answer to it but I can't get my head on to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "pure strings" - why wouldn't "232" be a pure string? Also: Please edit your question to show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: You tried *nothing*? Even not a naïve – but working – loop?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I couldn't land on these duplicate questions earlier. Thanks. @usr2564301

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str.isalpha` to determine if a string contains only letters. Then make a `set` from that (to make a container of unique elements) then determine the length of that `set`

```
>>> len(set(i for i in lst if i.isalpha()))
2
```

Comment: thank you cory :) but i've updated the list with a new input. Your solution doesn't solve that case. @CoryKramer

Comment: @YOLO For your updated list, you could try: `len(set(x for x in lst if x.replace(' ', '').isalpha()))`.